# Couldn't extract the data from large partition in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-2.1

I realized after sometime that my partition size in my Cassandra Data model was incorrect. And i had designed my primary key which created only one partition. So, i was getting read timeout in all the queries. I have fixed that issue by creating a new column family but now problem is how do i recover data from this partition any help would be appreciated. I have around 40GB of partition as given below :

```
38G     ./eventdata-7b5004e02bdc11e69ebb19dbbcf6d4b0
55M     ./eventdata-8f8317a01e5711e69ebb19dbbcf6d4b0
2.4M    ./eventdata-3c20dd401cf911e69ebb19dbbcf6d4b0
88K     ./eventdata-1866015012a911e69ebb19dbbcf6d4b0
```

So, to read the data i was using `sstable2json` to convert it in json but it gave this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
        at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.duplicate(HeapByteBuffer.java:107)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.composites.AbstractCType.sliceBytes(AbstractCType.java:369)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.composites.AbstractCompoundCellNameType.fromByteBuffer(AbstractCompoundCellNameType.java:101)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.composites.AbstractCType$Serializer.deserialize(AbstractCType.java:398)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.composites.AbstractCType$Serializer.deserialize(AbstractCType.java:382)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.IndexHelper$IndexInfo$Serializer.deserialize(IndexHelper.java:194)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.IndexHelper$IndexInfo$Serializer.deserialize(IndexHelper.java:174)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.RowIndexEntry$Serializer.deserialize(RowIndexEntry.java:129)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableScanner$KeyScanningIterator.computeNext(SSTableScanner.java:257)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableScanner$KeyScanningIterator.computeNext(SSTableScanner.java:231)
        at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:143)
        at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:138)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableScanner.hasNext(SSTableScanner.java:211)
        at org.apache.cassandra.tools.SSTableExport.export(SSTableExport.java:332)
        at org.apache.cassandra.tools.SSTableExport.export(SSTableExport.java:369)
        at org.apache.cassandra.tools.SSTableExport.export(SSTableExport.java:382)
        at org.apache.cassandra.tools.SSTableExport.main(SSTableExport.java:467)
ERROR 14:02:13 LEAK DETECTED: a reference (org.apache.cassandra.utils.concurrent.Ref$State@2835df6c) to class org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.S
STableReader$InstanceTidier@1560150690:/mnt/eventdata/eventdata-7b5004e02bdc11e69ebb19dbbcf6d4b0/./cw-eventdata-ka-2839 was not released before the reference was garbage collected
```

Then i was trying to split the sstable using `sstablesplit` utility but again i got the this error. I have Cassandra 2.1.12 running on a node having 8GB of RAM and 8GB of swap space :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.RandomAccessReader.readBytes(RandomAccessReader.java:375)
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.ByteBufferUtil.read(ByteBufferUtil.java:352)
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.ByteBufferUtil.readWithShortLength(ByteBufferUtil.java:331)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.composites.AbstractCType$Serializer.deserialize(AbstractCType.java:398)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.composites.AbstractCType$Serializer.deserialize(AbstractCType.java:382)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.IndexHelper$IndexInfo$Serializer.deserialize(IndexHelper.java:193)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.IndexHelper$IndexInfo$Serializer.deserialize(IndexHelper.java:174)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.RowIndexEntry$Serializer.deserialize(RowIndexEntry.java:129)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableScanner$KeyScanningIterator.computeNext(SSTableScanner.java:257)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableScanner$KeyScanningIterator.computeNext(SSTableScanner.java:231)
        at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:143)
        at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:138)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableScanner.hasNext(SSTableScanner.java:211)
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.MergeIterator$OneToOne.computeNext(MergeIterator.java:202)
        at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:143)
        at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:138)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionTask.runMayThrow(CompactionTask.java:181)
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:28)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionTask.executeInternal(CompactionTask.java:73)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.AbstractCompactionTask.execute(AbstractCompactionTask.java:59)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SSTableSplitter.split(SSTableSplitter.java:38)
        at org.apache.cassandra.tools.StandaloneSplitter.main(StandaloneSplitter.java:153)
```